# Counter method for objects in active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show a counter (index number) for each record in an active record relation.
When passing @students as a collection to the 'student' partial, a `student_counter` method is provided. Is there a similar method without using a partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to this then:

```
<% @students.each_with_index do |student, index| %>
  <%= student.name %> at <%= index %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. And I added @offset = (((params["page"] || 1).to_i - 1) * Student.default_per_page) + 1 to cater for paginated records